# Identical links in Outlook Email - why does only one render as a valid URL?

Tags: html, email, outlook

System I'm working on generates emails to the user. These are created by loading from a template and then filling in placeholders in the text with the appropriate information.

Many of these emails feature a link back to the system website. This is presented in two forms: a normal text underlined link and a faux-button.

When I have the system send emails to my hotmail account, these both work. However, when the same email gets sent to Outlook 2007, only the text link works. If you hover over the button it shows a blank URL of "http://" which, if clicked, opens a fresh browser window.

Examining the generated HTML, both links have a valid destination.

```
<td width="160" align="center" valign="middle">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile_hide">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td width="560" align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:14px; color:black; padding-bottom: 80px;">Please <a href="[valid link to site, with large querystring]" style="color: #009ddb; text-decoration: underline">choose a new password here</a>.</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </td>
  <td width="280" align="center">
     <table width="280" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
           <td width="280" align="center" valign="middle" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color:white; width:280px">
                <div>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:280px;" arcsize="63%" strokecolor="#32b8eb" fill="t">
                    <v:fill type="tile" />
                    <w:anchorlock/>
                    <center style="color:black;font-size:16px;width:280px;font-family:Calibri;">RESET YOUR PASSWORD NOW</center>
                    </v:roundrect>
                    <![endif]--><a href="[valid link to site, with large querystring]" style="border:1px solid #32b8eb; border-radius:25px;display:inline-block;font-size:16px;line-height:50px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none;height:50px;width:280px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;color:black;">RESET YOUR PASSWORD NOW</a>
                </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</td>
```

Why is the button email not being rendered correctly in Outlook? It can't be a blanket security feature as the text link works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess that the second href is the one that doesn't work. The reason is that you actually have three hrefs, but only two closing `</a>` tags. the second one in the Outlook-specific code lacks a closing tag and interferes withe the bottom href.

```
<!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:280px;" arcsize="63%" strokecolor="#32b8eb" fill="t">
  <v:fill type="tile" />
  <w:anchorlock/>
  <center style="color:black;font-size:16px;width:280px;font-family:Calibri;">RESET YOUR PASSWORD NOW</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
```

Specifically, it's this line: `<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:280px;" arcsize="63%" strokecolor="#32b8eb" fill="t">`

Close or remove the statement in the Outlook code. It's doing nothing right now except interfering with your bottom href. Your bottom href should start to work.

Good luck.

**Edit**

The Outlook-specific href gets closed by `</v:roundrect>`. An extra `</a>` is not needed. I think the code comes from https://buttons.cm. The expected behavior is to place a url to a button graphic you can use as a fallback, something like `https://buttons.cm/button.jpg`. Since there was no url and just a `http://`, I think this is still what caused the issue with Outlook. If I had all the code, I would test it, but I don't. I just wanted to add this to my fix to help anyone experiencing a similar problem a better thought out solution.

Comment: To be 100%  clear for anyone following up: it's the empty href tag in the outlook code that was the cause - the link has to go in there too.